# Apache conditional configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

Is it possible to dynamically include/exclude blocks somehow using env variables or the like?
Something in the lines of

```
<LocationMatch ...>
  SetEnvIf X-Requested-With XmlHttpRequest xhr
  <If xhr>
    SSLVerifyClient none
  </If>
  <If !xhr>
    SSLVerifyClient optional
  </If>
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Why not just place the AJAX endpoints on another location? The user won't see their URLs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In response to what you're trying solve given the Apache snippet rather than the actual question:

You can't enforce Client Certs after SSL handshake has taken place and certainly not after inspection of the HTTP headers, so your idea is not possible.

**Further more, `SSLVerifyClient optional` is not supported by any mainstream browser and leads to strange SSL connect errors.**

The only way to do this on the server side is to create a separate vhost dedicated to XHR requests.

However, on the client side have you tried `xhr.withCredentials = true`. From memory, this sends the client certs and any other auth data with the XHR request.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [like this](http://github.com/hiboma/apache-mod_ifenv)?

Comment: I would prefer to use "standard" modules. Would that directive actually work on a per-request basis? I want to configure stuff differently depending on HTTP headers.